# How to monitor the port state on ASA 5505

Tags: cisco-asa, configuration

On a Cisco *router* when you unplug a cable from an interface I normal see debug "int fa0/3 line up" etc

Is there some command to see this on an ASA 5505? I'm SSH'ing into it, do I need to use console to see this output?

I have a device and the port keeps going orange and I want to see why from the command line what is happening, its set to auto/auto, maybe it needs forcing to 100/duplex or soemthing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`show interface <intf_name>` works fine... you just need to be sure you have gone into enable mode on the ASA, otherwise, it won't parse...

```
mpenning-fw# show interface Ethernet 0/0
Interface Ethernet0/0 "", is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is 88E6095, BW 100 Mbps, DLY 100 usec
    Auto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(100 Mbps)
    Description: TIME WARNER CABLE MODEM
    Available but not configured via nameif
    MAC address 0019.0726.4a39, MTU not set
    IP address unassigned
    3255327 packets input, 1519248664 bytes, 0 no buffer
    Received 2070725 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
    0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
    0 L2 decode drops
    6346 switch ingress policy drops
    865668 packets output, 124791799 bytes, 0 underruns
    0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
    0 babbles, 0 late collisions, 0 deferred
    0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
    0 rate limit drops
    0 switch egress policy drops
mpenning-fw#
```

If you want to see log messages on the console, you could investigate `terminal monitor` from your ssh session.

Comment: Hi Mike, I was after live events rather than sh inf - but yes, term mon is what I need, if I set the logging to severity "warnings" then I see what I was looking for :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, port connection events show up in the console/ssh view without special configuration, although not necessarily with the level of detail you might be thinking.

[`debug switch iplm`](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/command/reference/d1.html#wp1996375) and [`debug switch manager`](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/command/reference/d1.html#wp1996490) both with the `errors` option give information specific to ports, but appear to be specific to PoE and VLAN events, which might not give you what you need.

ASDM has some graphing views, but these are specific to VLANs rather than specific ports - still, there might be something there that gives you a clue.

ASDM also gives you live logging with filtering, which might help, although the filters are really designed for firewall activity.  If you know what syslog ids might be of interest you can filter on those.

Comment: hmm, maybe its our set up, had I consoled to it I think it would have shown what I was looking for but I've turned on the monitor logging and it seems to be working now thanks dunxd

Answer (score 1):

The ASA OS will send interface up/down log messages to any logging destinations configured to severity level 4 (warnings) or higher.  That is to say that the ASA will send interface up/down log messages to logging destinations  set for warnings (4), notifications (5), informational (6), and debugging (7).

To see it on the console one must enable logging and then set the console logging destination to 4 or higher.

```
logging enable
logging console warnings
```

To see it on a VTY (Telnet/SSH) one must enable logging, set the terminal logging destination to 4 or higher, then set the terminal [as] monitor.

```
logging enable
logging monitor

terminal monitor
```

Note that the `terminal monitor` does ***not*** get entered in to the running-configuration.  It is set solely for the VTY from which it is entered and expires on logout from that VTY.

To remove the terminal monitor, use `terminal no monitor`.